# in/at your place, on/at your end

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

1. Is everything okay **at** your place?
   Is everything okay **in** your place?
2. Is everything okay **on** your end?
   Is everything okay **at** your end?

In the first example, are both the sentences grammatically correct?

In the second one, is the first sentence more appropriate than the second?

Comment: I don't want to post this link, but I feel I have to. It's kind of an urge on my end. https://www.lendio.com/blog/business-speak-rant-on-your-end/

Answer (score 9):

All of these sentences are grammatically correct, but there's more than grammar.

“Is everything okay **at** your place?” is idiomatic. “Is everything okay **in** your place?” is not. When *place* means *home*, the normal preposition to indicate a current location is *at*.

> Let's go **to** your place.
>   I'm **at** her place.
>   It takes half an hour to go **from** her place to mine.

While “in your place” is possible, it isn't common; in cases where the right preposition is *in*, the idiomatic phrase would use a different word: “in your house” or “in your apartment”. One reason “in your place” is rare is that “place” tends to have fuzzy limits: it means the location where someone lives. If the walls that separate the location from the outside are important, it is more common to use more precise words such as *house* or *apartment*. Another reason “in your place” sounds weird is that it usually refers to a completely different meaning of the word *place*: “in your place” means “if I were you”.

On the other hand, “**on** your end” and “**at** your end” are both idiomatic and pretty much synonymous. [US English favors *on*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+your+end%2Con+your+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20your%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20your%20end%3B%2Cc0) while [British English favors *at*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+your+end%2Con+your+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20your%20end%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20your%20end%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3):

1. Is everything okay at your place? is correct. Is everything okay in your place? is not. 'In your place' normally means 'As a substitute for you'.
2. Is everything okay at your end? is correct. Is everything okay on your end? is not. It's hard to think of how you would actually use the phrase 'on your end'.

Comment: I come across "on your end" quite frequently, and though I don't know if it's technically correct English it basically means "on your side" where there is a gap in the middle.  "I think the source of phone static is on your end."  "I'm done with my part of the project; now we're waiting on your end so that it is all complete."

Comment: Agree - I think these are correct usages of 'on your end'.

Comment: In "the source of phone static is on your end", this refers to the equpment that is physically with you, whereas "at your end" is more abstract: it is in your sphere of control, or your organisation, and may or may not be physically with you. In a case like this, there's probably not much difference. "Waiting on your end" is quite different, because "waiting on" is a technical term (or a rather unusual variant of "waiting for"). "Waiting at your end" wouldn't make sense. .

Comment: _Example: **Are there any problems at your end/on your end?** Both 'at your end' and 'on your end' can be used. However, the former is more preferred by British speakers, while the latter by American speakers and programmers._ (Excerpted from _Most Common Mistakes by Non-Native Speakers of English_ by Sergiy Zatsarynnyy.)